# XSD: how to define type with (1) attributes, (2) nested elements and (3) plain text content?

Tags: xsd, element, definition

Is it possible to define such element as HTML's "font" tag, which can contain all three types of subelements?

For example, I can write

<font size=3>This is <b>the</b> text</font>

How can I define is XSD, that font can contain:
1) attribute size
2) nested element B
3) text arount it

?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the type as [Content Type Mixed](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp).